# Split a row based on a value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in my Oracle database

```
TopCode BottomCode  Totalpeep
A   ABC123      100
B   BED456           45
```

I want a query that is to able to split the rows based on the Totalpeep / 20 e.g. there will be 5 groups for A and 3 groups for B, even if the Totalpeep is less than 20 then this must have one group

```
TopCode  BottomCode  Grp
A        ABC123      A1
A        ABC123      A2
A        ABC123      A3
A        ABC123      A4
A        ABC123      A5
B        BED456      B1
B        BED456      B2
B        BED456      B3
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy to achieve using connect by:

```
with sample_data (TopCode, BottomCode, Totalpeep) as (select 'A', 'ABC123', 100 from dual union all
                                                      select 'B', 'BED456', 45 from dual)
select topcode,
       bottomcode,
       topcode||level grp
from   sample_data
connect by prior topcode = topcode
           and prior dbms_random.value is not null
           and level <= ceil(totalpeep/20);

TOPCODE BOTTOMCODE GRP                                      
------- ---------- ----
A       ABC123     A1
A       ABC123     A2
A       ABC123     A3
A       ABC123     A4
A       ABC123     A5
B       BED456     B1
B       BED456     B2
B       BED456     B3
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a method:

1. **Dividing the column values** would give the **count of rows** you need to split.
2. Then further dividing by that count would divide it into **equal number of buckets**. And then the rest is **ROW GENERATOR** method.

**Test case:**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  topcode VARCHAR2(10),
  3  totalpeep NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('A', 100);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('B', 45);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

TOPCODE     TOTALPEEP
---------- ----------
A                 100
B                  45

SQL>
```

So, the SQL to create equal number of buckets based on the count:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT t.*, t.totalpeep/20 wt_bucket  FROM t )
  3  SELECT topcode, topcode||level
  4  FROM DATA
  5    CONNECT BY LEVEL          <= wt_bucket
  6  AND PRIOR topcode            = topcode
  7  AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
  8  /

TOPCODE    TOPCODE||LEVEL
---------- --------------------------------------------
A          A1
A          A2
A          A3
A          A4
A          A5
B          B1
B          B2

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

> even if the Totalpeep is less than 20 then this must have one group

In that case, the remaining bucket which is not used, should also be considered:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT t.*, t.totalpeep/20 wt_bucket  FROM t )
  3  SELECT topcode, topcode||level
  4  FROM DATA
  5    CONNECT BY LEVEL          <= ceil(wt_bucket)
  6  AND PRIOR topcode            = topcode
  7  AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
  8  /

TOPCODE    TOPCODE||LEVEL
---------- --------------------------------------------
A          A1
A          A2
A          A3
A          A4
A          A5
B          B1
B          B2
B          B3

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, for the group with values not as a whole number after dividing, you could consider them as well.