# Duplicate row in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, i have two rows

```
id|amount
 1|4
 2|1
```

How i can duplicate row where amount more than 1?

```
1|1
1|1
1|1
1|1
2|1
```

Comment: I have already answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28831409/3989608

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a row based on a column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091951/split-a-row-based-on-a-column-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily achievable by using connect by:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 4 amount from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 1 amount from dual)
select id, 1
from   sample_data
connect by prior id = id
           and prior dbms_random.value is not null
           and level <= amount;

        ID          1
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          1
         1          1
         1          1
         2          1
```